# Eclipse Juno for C/C++ Insert space for tab doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, perl, eclipse-cdt

I just found **Eclipse Juno** for C/C++ "**Insert space for tab**" doesn't work. Juno for Java works. Anybody has the same issue? Is there a way to run a **script** to change **tabs** to **4-spaces** in all **.cpp** and **.h** files before I check in my changes? Anybody can help with the script? thanks,

**Edit:**

I am in Linux.

**Edit2**

[this](http://adrienbailly.wordpress.com/2010/04/17/replace-tabs-by-spaces-in-files/) works too:

find ./ -name '*.cpp' -exec sed -i 's/\t/    /g' {} \;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is a one-liner from your terminal:

```
$ perl -pi.bak -e 's{\t}{    }g' *.cpp *.h
```

The '.bak' argument will create a backup of your files (e.g. test.cpp --> test.cpp.bak)

For Windows, use double-quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: can you makes it start a location and traverses down all subfolders to modify all files within that directory tree? thanks

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA : What's your OS?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA : `$ find location/ -name "*.cpp" | perl -pi.bak -e 's{\t}{    }g'` should do it for the .cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get it working (rather than using a script):

- Go to 'Window' -> 'Preferences'
- In tree select: C/C++ -> Code Style -> Formatter
- Click 'Edit' button
- Tab 'Identation': Set 'Tab policy' to 'Spaces only' (poke around if different from the editor the settings of which i was fixing)
- Click 'Apply'/'Ok'

HTH